# "Don't you..." question

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I'm studying English for 10 months. I suppose myself to know it quite well now. But I'm confused about one thing. I noticed that some of my English speaking friends sometimes ask

> "Don't you tired/hungry/etc?"

Is this normal/grammatically correct to make such questions? Because I've googled by phrases and found quite a lot of examples of using such questions?

Here are some examples:

- http://youtube.com/watch?v=D6IUow9g_1g (the last comment by noangelsaroundme);
- http://about-ukraine.net/last-february-for-ukraine.html (chapter "February 16")
- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121224104020AA0tWKv (question title)

Comment: You could be referring to the pop culture of _Do you even lift, brah?_ which led to people asking stupid questions like _Do you even hungry?_

Comment: Hi Oleg, this is a vaild question, and I'd say it's on topic. However, you can  improve it by doing some research first and including your finds in the post. For example, you could say that the grammer doesn't seem to match prescribed usages and include a link to an online source to prove it.

Comment: "Don't you tired?" would not be considered proper English in the US.  It would be something like "Aren't you tired?"

Comment: @TusharRaj Here is some examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6IUow9g_1g (the last comment by noangelsaroundme); http://www.about-ukraine.net/last-february-for-ukraine.html (chapter "February 16"); https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121224104020AA0tWKv (question title)

Comment: @HotLicks is right. Alternatively, if you want to keep the "don't you" construction, you could add "feel", as in "Don't you *feel* tired/hungry/etc?".

Comment: @Oleg: You don't have to convince me. I upvoted to bring the score back to zero. Include these links in the question by editing it. The edit button(text) is right below the question.

Comment: Your examples are 3 examples of improper English.  The first may just be sloppy writing.  The second is "Don`t you bored of all this? So we gradually coming to the main part" -- clearly a non-native English speaker.  The third is too short to get  reading.

Comment: @TusharRaj Thanks. I've found it already. But lets get back to the question: can I use such form in common speech?

Comment: @Oleg: I'm from India, and I've never heard this before, so unfortunately I'm not in a position to answer. However, others on this site can speak for their respective areas, and maybe some areas recognize this usage. I'm interested in this question and I was attempting to stop this post getting downvoted. I'm not withholding an answer. I don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't you tired?" is grammatically incorrect in Standard English, but may be part of the local dialect.

Auxiliary forms such as *do, does, did* are used with a main verb to frame a question. For example: "Do you speak German?", "Don't you speak German?", where the infinitive *speak* is present.

But they have no grammatical function in a sentence such as in the one you quoted, because there's no main verb. For example, in the sentence "Don't you tired?", *tired* is not a verb, but an adjective. Such a sentence is unacceptable in Standard English.

(Note: when we conduct a Google search, it brings up all that it can find in the cyberspace, which is a free-for-all. Since it's natural for us to google for answers, it's recommended that you do it by typing, as in this case, say, "How to form questions in English". You might end up on an authentic site that you could learn from.)

Comment: Hi Sankarne, your answer sounds a bit condescending. This is a site about usage. The OP has heard English-speakers talking this way, stands to reason that some regions might consider this accpetable informally, if not grammatical. The OP is NOT asking for a way to paraphrase these statements to be grammatical. The points you made are better suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Although it's interesting to learn about these anomalies, it would be good not to use such a "language", especially as a learner. A native speaker may speak such a language and get away with it.

Comment: An additional perspective with googling is that just because there are lots of examples, it doesn't mean that it is an accepted alternative. There are countless examples of 'the the' on the internet, but they are universally recognized as errors.